# Recruiters can see my real name

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow-jobs

It seems that recruiters can see my real name on the jobs section. This is pretty weird and unexpected. How do you remove it? Where is it warned about?

Comment: Why would you **not** want a recruiter to see your real name? How is he going to call you and offer you a job without it? Do you put your fake name on your CV? I'm guessing not ...

Comment: Has anyone ever called you and offered you a job from looking at a profile only? My guess is he will want to talk to you, maybe ask some questions, and progress the conversation off SO. He can get your real name then. Meanwhile if your current employer happens to use SO, they can see you're looking for something else to do.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you go to your Jobs profile there are two fields

- Display Name
- Profile Name

These are described as such:

- Display Name: How you appear to other users on the Stack Overflow Q&A Network.
- Profile Name: How you appear to employers, your private Teams, and to other users when you share your Developer Story.

---

To change these:

- Go to Jobs

  [image: Select Jobs]
- Click Developer Profile 
  [image: Select Developer Profile]
- Click Edit next to your profile picture (it only appears on mouse over)
  [image: Mouse Over, Click Edit]
- Modify one or both the fields listed above 
  [image: Modify Names as Needed]

---

A recruiter sees the following. After this header, they see the "Traditional View" of your Developer Story (at least I do, I can't remember if I changed that from the Story view at one point or not).

The blacked out fields, in order from top to bottom:

- Full Name (from the settings above)
- Current job title (supplied in your developer story)
- Location (supplied in your developer profile)
- URL to personal site (supplied in your profile)

[image: Recruiter View]

Comment: Can you add screenshots? The only display name I see is the general profile one, and it shows my pseudonym.

Comment: @Carlos I've added screenshots for you

Comment: Cool thanks. I hadn't thought the edit button would reveal two names. In addition, it's not clear what the recruiter sees. I only found out because a recruiter called me, having spotted me on the site.

Comment: @Carlos I added a screenshot of my profile as seen from the recruiter's point of view.

Answer (score -2):

In regards to your question about *"Where is it warned about?"* this is covered in [Privacy Notice for Stack Overflow Talent and Jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/privacy-policy/talent):

> ### What information we collect
>
> Whether you are a recruiter seeking to hire on our Talent platform, or are an unregistered user or a registered account holder
>   using our Jobs platform while seeking employment opportunities, we
>   collect certain account registration information on you.
>
> For job seekers on the Jobs platform, **we collect your name**, location,
>   email and resume (where applicable) along with certain optional
>   information including your phone number, job matching preferences
>   (optional)
>
> - Their profile & developer story (includes all their work history, etc)
> - Site activity (i.e. monitoring which jobs they've interacted with on our site)
> - A cover letter (where applicable).

Emphasis added.

Comment: That just says it is collected, not displayed.

Comment: Yes, it's collected as part of your profile; recruiters can see your profile @patricksweeney . I was, however, addressing the "warning" part. Bring informed this information is collected *is* your "warning.

Comment: Effectively to stop this you need to falsify your own data?